# Include property declared in body of data class in toString() in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, tostring

In Kotlin, is it possible to have a property, that's declared in the body of a data class, be included in the default `toString()` result?

```
data class A(val b:Int = 0) {
    val c: Int = 0
}
println(A())
```

Prints: `A(b=0)`
Desired: `A(b=0, c=0)`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the generated `toString`, that will only have the properties declared in the primary constructor (as described in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes)). However, you can always override `toString` yourself if you want to:

```
data class A(val b:Int = 0) {
    val c: Int = 0

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "A(b=$b, c=$c)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame because calculated properties (like age from a birthdate etc.) are omitted then. I just don't see, why they are not printed, as long as they are declared as public properties.